# Capitalise all characters within certain characters?

Tags: vim

Say I have a few lines of text:

```
--:hello:--
my name is bob
how are you

--:goodbye:--
it was nice to meet you
see you later
```

and I want to capitalise everything between the "--:" and ":--", is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

This command should do it:

```
:%s/--:\(.*\):--/--:\U\1:--/g
```

Answer (score 0):

I would search for enough to get your cursor on the word (the e puts the cursor at the end of the match). Then use gUiw to capitalise the word.

```
/--:./e
gUiw
```

Then just hit 'n' and '.' to move to the next search result and repeat the change.

If there are too many to do manually, you could do the first one, then record a macro of you doing the second one with

```
qqn.q
```

qq starts the recording 
n. goes to next and repeats the captialisation 
q stops the recording

Then you could do 100@q to perform the change on the next 100 matches.